# Fastest Way to Retrieve a Single Int from SQLite in c++

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have a c++ container of up to 3 strings, and many times just one string.

I need to get one int value from a sqlite dB for each string in the container, and I was wondering if there is a faster way than a prepared statement?

The way I have it right now

```
int Idx{}; // set to 0
std::for_each(container.begin(), container.end(), [](string& item) {
    sqlite3_prepared_v2( 
        db, 
        ("SELECT categoryId FROM table WHERE item='" + item + "'").c_str(), 
        -1, 
        &stmt, 
        NULL 
    );
    sqlite3_step(stmt); // goto the first result
    Idx += sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0); // add to my Idx
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt); // finalize
};
```

Comment: *Aside*: Consider the use of [placeholders](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) to avoid [SQL injection attacks](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: interesting...I will most definitely do that. Thanks for the tip